# parse HTML into an array

Tags: php

I have an array that is being returned from a rss feed.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://www.rssfeed');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }

    $limit = 5;

    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
        echo '<div><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';


        echo $description.'</div>';

    }
```

The `$description` variable is an array value, which is a table.  So i can't format the content of the table without putting it in an array.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="8"><tbody><tr><td width="80px"><a href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/example"><img border="0" src="http://example.jpg"></a></td><td><div><span><strong>Â£145.00</strong></span></div><div>End Date: <span>13-Aug 16:14</span></div><div>Buy It Now for only: US Â£145.00</div><a href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/example">Buy it now</a><span>  |  </span><a href="http://cgi1.ebay.co.uk/example">Add to watch list</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

How do i get the content(including tags) of `td` and put into an array?

I tried this but the array values are blank.

```
$table = new DOMDocument(); 
$table->loadHTML($description);
    $new_table = array();
    foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'cell' => $node->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue
            );
        array_push($new_table, $item);
    }
```

Comment: Create a new `DOMDocument` using `$table = new DOMDocument(); $table->loadHTML($description);` and then handle that as you did your RSS feed.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your input looks like and what the expected output is; The sentence "The $description variable is an array value, which is a table." really confuses me. can you please clarify ?

Comment: @LaurentS.  I mean the array value is the table html.

Comment: @Phylogenesis but the table html doesn't have any tag names?  What should i use instead of `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: @Phylogenesis, see edit.. i tried your suggestion, doesn't work.

Comment: Why split into rows first? `foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) { array_push($new_table, $node->nodeValue); }`.

Comment: Thanks but the tags of td content are being stripped? How do i keep the tags in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see why array values are blank.

`DOMDocument::nodeValue` property is [returning the textContent of the node](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue).

The first `td` node selected is one containing no text content:

```
<td width="80px">
    <a href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/example">
        <img border="0" src="http://example.jpg">
    </a>
</td>
```

Also [`Document::saveHTML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) dumps the HTML representation of the `DOMElement` as string. For example,

```
$table = new DOMDocument(); 
$table->loadHTML($description);
$new_table = [];

foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('td') as $node) {
    array_push($new_table, [
       'cell' => $table->saveHTML($node)
    ]);
}
```